# SQL Image doesn't display with header-content

Tags: php, mysql

I have images stored on a MySQL database, longblob type column, but when I try to display them on the browser on Chorme I only see a little white box, and on Firefox I see and error message saying that the image file has a problem.

This is what I use to display the image.

```
$query = "SELECT file, type FROM uploads WHERE ref = '$ref'";
$statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

header("Content-Type: " . $row["type"]);
echo $row["file"];
```

Note: `$row["type"]` is the MIME type of the file.
I think that the image isn't corrupted because I can display it with this.

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['file'] ).'"/>';
```

But I need it the other way, curious thing is that few days ago it worked fine with the same code. Perhaps MySQL fault?

**Edit**
The code of the upload.

```
function uploader_upload($file, $ref) {

    $uploader = $_LOGIN["userid"];      
    $name = $file["name"];
    $type = $file["type"];
    $tmp_name = $file["tmp_name"];
    $note = $file["note"];
    $insert_file = mysql_escape_string(file_get_contents($tmp_name));           


    $query = "INSERT INTO uploads (file, name, type, uploader, ref, note) VALUES ('$insert_file', '$name', '$type', '$uploader', '$ref', '$note')";
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $refs[] = $ref;

    return $refs;
}
```

Comment: uneed to decryot ur image

Comment: @rupesh I try `base64_decode()` but still the same, also the `base64_encode()` like the `echo` that works but nothing.

Comment: header("Content-Type: " . $row["type"]); is wrong approach to call image

Comment: @rupesh Type is the MIME type of the file, usually image/png or image/jpeg. And this is what that line looks `Content-Type: image/png`. If I a check on the browser it have the correct header.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I find the problem, seems that an `echo` slipped with the includes of that php and it was corrupting the image.

If someone have the same problem, just make sure that no `echo` or `print` or any error shows.